# Why is a column filled automatically when using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to fill one cell with a 'FormulaR1C1', but the result is the entire column filled.

I have a table-like sheet, with a header, and some fields to be filled automatically in the rows used. To achieve this, I have:

```
Sheet1.Cells(R, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1] * R[0]C[-2]"
```

Where 'R' is the row needed. (This line updates column "F".)

Somehow this line fills all the cells in that column with the Formula, only leaving the header unchanged.

I can reproduce that without running my code, using that line on the immediate-window. The same for every column I try.

The only time that doesn't happen is when there's more data in the column, then it works correctly, filling only the row asked.

Comment: If you need automatic fill, can you add an IF() statement to check if values are present and then execute your command (`Cells().Offset()` is a nice feature), otherwise return an empty string or zero value?  Tables tend to auto-fill a column with formulas, regardless of the reference type, in order to keep things consistent.

Comment: If you have that `R` variable in the formula, this means that the formula it is added during an iteration. If you do not show us all the code, it is difficult to explain Why. But certainly only this code line does not fill all the column. So, what is `R` from the formula and in which context do you use the code line you show us?

Comment: The problem also happens if I change R to a constant

Comment: @MarkMoretto I think you are right, it's not a code problem. Excel likes to autofill formulas, if I use the "Value" property in the same code it works fine (just not the way I want :/).

Comment: I'll see if just "Formula" works, I can do it with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a table-like sheet

If it's an actual table in a sheet and not a table-like sheet then this should work....

Manually (in Excel 365) you can go to **File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options > Fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns.**

In VBA before you add the formula use
`Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False`

Adds a formula to row 3, column 2 of Table1:

```
Sub test()

    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(3).Range(2).Formula = "=1"
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Before reading you anwer I changed my code to work without formulas. But continuing the work on my sheet I realised this autofill thing was annoyingly happening every time. Manually disabling it solved the issue for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Sheets(1)

With Ws
    r = .Range("e" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("f2", "f" & r).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1] * R[0]C[-2]"
    'To get the non-formula value, run below
    '.Range("f2", "f" & r).Value = .Range("f2", "f" & r).Value
End With
```